# ConTeXt: Enumeration, Comments cause undefined control sequence startformula error

Tags: errors, comments, context-mkii

I'm a LaTeX user working through some ConTeXt tutorials, and hit a brick wall pretty early. It makes me wonder if something is wrong with my setup, or if I'm not understanding something pretty fundamental, or if ConTeXt is a bit more brittle than I had hoped. I'm using MacTeX-2012.

I'm getting errors when using both a formula and an enumeration with the `letter` option. Leaving out the `letter` option, this works great:

```
\defineenumeration[guess][location=left]
\starttext
  \startformula
    x = no error
  \stopformula
  \guess This is just a guess.

\stoptext
```

The following, however, causes `texexec` to fail with `Undefined control sequence` on `\startformula` and `\stopformula`:

```
\defineenumeration[guess][location=left, letter=it]
\starttext
  \startformula
    x = error
  \stopformula
  \guess This is just a guess.

\stoptext
```

Taking out the `formula` removes the error, so the enumeration with the `letter=it` option is working fine on its own.

In testing this, I discovered (to my surprise) that commenting out the `letter` option gives the same error:

```
\defineenumeration[guess][location=left] %, letter=it]
\starttext
  \startformula
    x = error
  \stopformula
  \guess This is just a guess.

\stoptext
```

But taking out the `=` sign fixes it. No error when running:

```
\defineenumeration[guess][location=left] %, letter it]
\starttext
  \startformula
    x = no error
  \stopformula
  \guess This is just a guess.

\stoptext
```

However, it's not just the equals sign, as this works without error:

```
\defineenumeration[guess][location=left] %, bar=baz]
\starttext
  \startformula
    x = no error
  \stopformula
  \guess This is just a guess.

\stoptext
```

I am very confused. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Why are using MkII?  If you don't have any particular reason not to use MkIV, i.e. `context` instead of `texexec`, then imho it's better to use MkIV.  (MkII is no longer being developed, so in case of bugs/feature requests you're basically on your own.)

Comment: I have no trouble running your example using `context` with [ConTeXt standalone](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/ConTeXt_Standalone#Unix-like_platforms_.28Linux.2FMacOS_X.2FFreeBSD.2FSolaris.29). ConTeXt standalone is very quick and easy to install and a lot more up-to-date, though you should use MkIV as @mbork says. Try that and see if it fixes your problems.

Comment: Wow... using `context` worked perfectly. I've read tons of documentation that praise `texexec` for running as many times as necessary to get cross references and citations right. Am I reading out-of-date documentation? Does `context` do this as well? If someone puts this as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Yes, `context` will do that as well. I suspect what you're reading is out-of-date. I rely on this site and the ConTeXt wiki for all my info. :)

Comment: As a personal choice, I prefer to use `\startguess ... \stopguess` rather than `\guess ... \par`. The latter can sometimes fail with a weird error message if the `\par` (empty line in the end) in missing.

Comment: @Aditya Yes, I prefer those too. I just changed it to make all the MWEs smaller (and found the need for `\par` the hard way!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some reason the code you provided makes ConTeXt switch to the dutch interface (I have no clue why). In the dutch interface the command `\startformula` is not defined and hence you get an error. You can process the file with

```
texexec --interface=en file.tex
```

This forces ConTeXt to use MkII with the English interface and the file is processed.

However, as already pointed out in the comments you should probably better use ConTeXt MkIV, which uses the command `context` instead of `texexec`. You will get full Unicode support and much easier font handling.

BTW: I have no clue what the `letter=it` option is supposed to do. Where did you find it documented?

Comment: Thanks! I was using the "LaTeX in proper ConTeXt" tutorial from http://www.berenddeboer.net/tex/. Using `letter=it` is supposed to make the text italic---and it works, in Dutch mode. And it must be the problem: using `style=italic` (which I got from the wiki) causes `texexec` to run in English, and I get no errors. Weird. Will use ConTeXt MkIV from now on, and stick to more official documentation.

Comment: I think `style=it` instead will do the trick in MkIV.

Comment: If it doesn't, try `headstyle=it`. There's [a reference on the wiki](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setupdescriptions).

Comment: @DanielLyons So `it` and `italic` are the same? There's no mention of either on the page you linked to, and that's for descriptions, not enumerations. Multiple ways to do the same thing, incomplete documentation, weird bugs when switching to MkIV and/or Standalone, fourteen different table environments (with no simple `booktabs`)... I have to say learning ConTeXt has not exactly been a pleasant experience.

Comment: @SamBritt `\it` is the low-level switch to select the italic font. `italic` is defined as `\definealternativestyle[italic][\it][]`, that enables you to use it as a style: `style=italic` or as a font switch: `{\italic Some text}`

Comment: FWIW, I've never seen `italic` in a context like this. `it` works by analogy to `bf` and `tt` and the other font commands. I can't say learning ConTeXt has been the easiest process for me either but I find it usually is both easier to use and more consistent than the other alternatives. It is plagued by its own continuous evolution and documentation problems. But I have found (so far) it's worth it in the end. Asking questions here has resolved all of my problems so far. I hope you'll stick with it and ask lots more, and hopefully we can get the documentation up to speed as we go.